# Best way/format to convert a PDF to be able to read on android?

Tags: pdf, android, mobile-phone, ebook, epub

I have a pdf ebook, a Technical book that conatins a lot of code.

Reading it as pdf is slow plus reflowing text in the pdf reader removes all the formatting.

I tried converting it to epub using calibre but that too removes all the formatting.

The only pleasant experience I have had reading a technical book on my phone is as chm but I can't find anything to convert pdf to chm(Found a couple of softwares but that didn't do a good job).

Has anyone had successfully experience in reading a technical pdf ebook on a android phone?

Comment: @GAThrawn Please do not flag for migration to Android SE. Until it is out of Beta questions can't be migrated, and there is no planned migration path from Super User to Android.

Comment: There is a very similar question on Android Enthusiasts already: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2188/best-way-to-read-programming-technical-math-pdfs-on-android-device

Answer (score 1):

I enjoy reading PDFs on my Droid X, though I found it painstakingly slow on my last phone, a Droid Eris, no matter which reader I used. I would only recommend reading PDFs on a speedy phone.

I usually reflow the text for reading, unless it happens to be set in columns narrow enough to fit readably on my screen. For PDFs with complex layouts and formatting—which I usually don't read on my phone—I tend to stick with reading/reflowed mode (unless it looks terrible, with line breaks and spaces in all the wrong places, etc.) and occasionally check the page view mode to see what I'm missing. Switching between views can be annoying, but it's not too bad if there are narrow sections of text that I can focus on one at a time.

How complicated is the formatting, and would it be possible to convert to HTML? If that's an option, I'd recommend playing around with the command-line options in [pdftohtml](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdftohtml/), which Calibre uses to convert PDFs to HTML.